# How to combine two jointplots with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want two jointplots to be plotted together, not on different figures. How can I do that?

I tried

```py
sns.jointplot(column_headers[4],column_headers[6],data=df,color="blue")
sns.jointplot(column_headers[4],column_headers[6],data=typesatt[0],color="red")
```

It gave me two different figures

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to merge your dataframes, adding a hue column. Here is an example starting from some test data. Note that when using multiple distributions, in order to make the plot more readable, seaborn automatically changes the marginal plots from histograms to kdeplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20221129)
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'col4': np.random.randn(1000).cumsum(),
                    'col6': np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()})
dfr = pd.DataFrame({'col4': np.random.randn(100).cumsum(),
                    'col6': np.random.randn(100).cumsum()})
df_merged = pd.DataFrame({'col4': pd.concat([dfb['col4'], dfr['col4']]),
                          'col6': pd.concat([dfb['col6'], dfr['col6']]),
                          'origin': ['dfb'] * len(dfb) + ['dfr'] * len(dfr)}).reset_index()

sns.jointplot(x='col4', y='col6', hue='origin', data=df_merged, palette=["blue", "red"])
```

[image: sns.jointplot from two dataframes]